# How to Transfer xml file from remote server to another server

Tags: c#

I have  some problem for- transfer xml file from one server to another using ip address ,same network is working fine,but different network is not working,cant able to connect,anybody can help me to solve this

Comment: What code do you have?

Comment: The question is much too broad but it sounds like you're using the internal IP of the target server which is only available inside its own network. In order to communicate with something it needs to be visible to the outside world but I'm no networking expert.

Comment: Are you having issues with all file types or just xml?  I think this is really a connection issue and nothing to do with xml.  Start by using cmd.exe > Ping IP.  Then also try computer name instead of IP.  Results will give me a lot of info to help solve issue.

Comment: @Jsantos Thanks For Reply i using c-sharp socket

Comment: @Alex Paven --- Thanks for reply actually concept is i hosted my content in cloud,its a web applicaton when online is no problem ,when offline not possible to use that url,so that time we already hosted same content in local machine for billing purpose but database not updated,so that  time when once form save that datas saved in xml file also,so when online time that xml file will transfer to cloud server,and update that cloud database,that purpose asking i want to connect

Comment: @jdweng  Thanks for reply,i never try others,i try with only xml file

Comment: and anybody for sample coding for that please send me for solving this

Comment: You're supposed to share that code on the question

Comment: I guess you need to save xml locally when off-line, and then upload xml file to cloud when you come back on-line.

Comment: @ jdweng  ---   Yes Correct

Comment: @JSantos --- Ok